# Extract from archive into memory - libarchive

Tags: c++, c, libarchive

I've been learning how to use `libarchive` and the docs are quite helpful.
However, I can't seem to figure out a way to extract it directly into memory instead of writing it to a file. Is this possible? Thanks!

The example I've been looking at and modifying:
https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/Examples#A_Complete_Extractor

Comment: You can probably ask the author directly through issues on github.

Comment: Same question. Any updates?